# Finest good cover of a topological space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. Does there exists a good open cover $\left\{ U_{a}\right\}_{a\in I}$ finer than any other open cover of $X$?

> A **good cover** $\{U_\alpha\}_\alpha$ of $X$ is a collection of open subsets of $X$ such that the intersection of finitely many $U_\alpha$ is contractible.

My question is related to the definition of Cech cohomology groups: there you start with a given good open cover and then you take the limit of finer and finer good open covers, so I figured that for that limit to exist there should exist a "finest cover".

Comment: What does finer here mean? That any other open cover is a subset of $\{U_a\}_{a \in I}$? If so, certainly the topology on $X$ itself is, by definition, such a cover.

Comment: In most cases, no. In the discrete topology, yes. Possibly a few others. But the most interesting topologies do not have a "finest" open cover.

Comment: @StefanHamcke My guess: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_cover_%28algebraic_topology%29 The intersection of a finite number of open sets in the cover is contractible.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the definition and adding a little bit of context the OP supplied in a comment (that was made on a now-deleted answer).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Thanks.